# problem to install QGis

Tags: updates, software-sources, qgis

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy from 20.04. I try to install Qgis following the instructions (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html). When I try to run sudo apt update I get the message: Malformed stanza 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources (type) The list of sources could not be read.

This is the string I added
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

Anyone knows where I make a mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, if you're running 22.04 then you shouldn't have "focal" repositories (focal = 20.04).

Comment: I solved the problem, maybe in an unfair way. I erased the content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources. Then I run sudo apt update & upgrade. Finally I got QGis though not the latest version. I could also open synaptics that was blocked before

Answer (score 0):

> I get the message: Malformed stanza 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources (type) The list of sources could not be read.

Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425594/edit) your question including output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources` to see what is the malformed stanza 1 error means.

I tried your source based on your link. it **Works** for me :

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr
Suites: jammy
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

For Alternative software repositories you can add `qgis.list` from Ubuntu GIS repository :

- **Stable :**

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy main 
  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy main
  ```
- **Unstable :**

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu jammy main 
  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu jammy main
  ```

**Try** to check your Qgis package candidate, run :

```
apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.26.2+36jammy
  Version table:
     1:3.26.2+36jammy 500
        500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     3.22.4+dfsg-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

You can see above detail, you can get latest release of Qgis version 3.26.

Comment: # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223)]/ focal main restricted

deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

is this the first stanza?

Comment: @CARLOCITTER Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425594/edit) your question including output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources` and also your source list form `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Don't use unreadable code on this comment section.